# Dropdown is not working in Materialize design with fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, material-design, fabricjs

I am using materialize design and fabric js library. I want to change font style of text in canvas. Before materialize design i used bootstrap then it was working fine. But right now i am using materialize design place of bootstrap then my dropdown is not working.

**WITHOUT MATERIALIZE DESIGN (Dropdown is working).**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$('#font').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
    obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
  oText.bringToFront();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>
<select id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550" style="border:1px solid #333"></canvas>
```

**WITH MATERIALIZE DESIGN (Dropdown is not working).**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$('#font').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
    obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
  oText.bringToFront();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">

<button class="btn" onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>
<select id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550" style="border:1px solid #333"></canvas>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to use materialize design with fabric js. And i want to change font style of text in canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialization your select box with materialize.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#font').material_select();
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#font').material_select();
  });

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$('#font').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
    obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
  oText.bringToFront();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">

<button class="btn" onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>
<select id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550" style="border:1px solid #333"></canvas>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```